# Erro no Typescript: Type 'K' cannot be used to index type 'T'

Tags: javascript, typescript, genéricos

Estou começando com TypeScript e travei na hora de tipar a seguinte função:

```
const pickProp = prop => obj => obj[prop]
```

Estou tentando desta maneira:

```
const pickProp = <K>(prop: K) => <T extends { [K in keyof T]: any }>(obj: T) => obj[prop]
```

E estou recebendo o seguinte erro:

> ```
> Type 'K' cannot be used to index type 'T'.
> ```

Como seria possivel tipar a função `pickProp`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JMedeiros, esse site é apenas para perguntas em português.

Se entendi direito a intuição do seu código, você está tentando criar uma função que recebe o nome de uma propriedade, e retorna uma outra função para capturar o valor dessa propriedade dos objetos passados a ela, correto?

O que você está tentando fazer pode ser obtido com o seguinte código:

```js
function pickProp<T extends string | number | symbol>(prop: T) {
    return function<V extends {[key in T]: any}>(obj: V) {
        return obj[prop]
    }
}
```

Note que `K` (ou `key`) não é um dos valore de `keyof T`, `K` é um valor de `T`, pois `T` é a própria propriedade, não um objeto.

Eu também precisei assegurar que `T` deve ser do tipo `string`, `number` ou `symbol`, pois esses são os tipos de propriedades válidas para um objeto, do contrário o objeto genérico `{[key in T]: any}` não seria válido,